# How do I modify the text of a JTextfield from a different class? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a calculator as practice (I'm pretty bad at Java), but now I face a problem that I can't fix. I have a frame with a CardLayout, and on one of those cards is a JTextfield. I made the textfield in my main class:
`JTextField textfield = new JTextField();`, and did some things with it:

```java
textfield.setBounds(50, 130, 380, 60);
textfield.setEditable(false);
textfield.setFont(font);
```

Now, I want to modify the text on the textfield from a different class (which makes the calculator work): `main.textfield.setText(main.textfield.getText() + "ans");`, but that doesn't work. I am trying to modify the text in an ActionPerformed method.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I tried doing it via a method in my main class, and repainting and revalidating the frame and the panel, which both didn't work.

@DanielJunglas asked for more information so here we go :p. I'll all the code that could possibly have effect on my problem.

```java
        frame.setBounds(700, 250, 500, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        contPanel.setLayout(cards);   //set the cardlayout to the container panel
        contPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 700);
        
        createBegPanel();   //creating the panels
        createNorPanel();
        createTriPanel();
        //createEquPanel();
        
        contPanel.add(beginPanel, "p1");
        contPanel.add(normalCalcPanel, "p2");
        contPanel.add(triCalcPanel, "p3");
        //contPanel.add(equCalcPanel, "p4");
        cards.show(contPanel, "p1");
        
        frame.add(contPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

```java
public void createNorPanel() {   //these are the things i do with the textfield
        textfield.setBounds(50, 130, 380, 60);
        textfield.setEditable(false);
        textfield.setFont(font);
```

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
        main.textfield.setText("test");
```

So any button is pressed, it should set the text of the textfield to 'text', but it doesnt. Is this enough info?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us how and what you have tried so far?

Comment: In addition to showing the relevant parts of your code (or even better: a minimal working example), you also need to tell us what exactly does not work. Does the code not compile, does the update not show on the screen, is an exception raised? In general, `setText()` is the right thing to do do set the text.

Comment: @DanielJunglas it does not give error messages, the text just does not show up on the texfield.

Comment: If the text does not show up then you have to show us code. There are a lot of things that could cause this problem.

Comment: @DanielJunglas all of my code?

Comment: The description of what code to post to make analysis simple is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Create a textField getter method in the main class, and execute the getter method in the ActionListener class.

Comment: I had already tried that, but it doesn't work either

Comment: If you are using Swing, mention that or add a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you never call `actionPerformed`.

If you have a button then you need to add an `ActionListener` to it that implements the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

It looks like you have a class  that implements an `ActionListener` (which is generally not a good solution). In that case you have to add `this` as `ActionListener` to the button.

```java
JButton b = new JButton();
b.addActionListener(this);
```

A better solution would be to add a separate `ActionListener` to each button.

```java
JButton b = new JButton();
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        main.textfield.setText("test");
    }
});
```

`ActionListener` is a functional interface (it has only one method) wich means you could also use a Lambda expression.

```java
b.addActionListener(e -> main.textfield.setText("test"));
```

Comment: I did ad an actionlistener to the buttons, and the other commands in de actionperformed method work perfectly fine

Comment: Then `setText()` should work. I can't reproduce your problem. Do you see the textfield at all?

Comment: Yes I did. I finally found a solution for my problem. I made the textfield static, and now i dont have any problems anymore. Thanks for all your good help!